# In a Hilbert-style proof system, does every theorem have a non-redundant proof?

Tags: proof-theory

Consider the famous system of axioms:
 $1$. $A \to (B \to A)$. 
 $2$. $(A \to (B \to C)) \to ((A \to B) \to (A \to C))$. 
 $3$. $(\neg A \to \neg B) \to (B \to A)$, along with the inference rule modus ponens. A proof of a theorem T is said to be non-redundant if there are no repetitions in the sequence of statements, and if the deletion of any number of lines makes it no longer a proof of T. Of course, that system of axioms is just one example. The more general question is, is it true that in any Hilbert-style set of axioms and inference rules, every theorem has a non-redundant proof? To be fair, I am not entirely sure that my strict, formal definition of non-redundant proof matches the intuitive notion of non-redundant proof.

Comment: Can't we just remove duplications and unnecessary statements until we obtain a non-redundant derivation?

Comment: Carl is right. Starting with the last statement in your proof and going backwards, test: if I remove this statement, is it still a proof of $T$? Anytime a statement passes that test, remove it. When you are finished, what remains will be a non-redundant proof of $T$. In particular, any repetions of a statement already in the proof are removable, so there will be no repeated statements.